# jQuery - Slideshow with different sized images and text

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need some sort of slideshow, with text (something like [moving boxes](http://css-tricks.com/moving-boxes/) would be nice).

I have tried several, but i'm always having problems with different sized images (the images can be for eg. 500px x 300px, but the next one can be 500px, 300px), this gives some problems with the pictures ...

I hope you understand what i mean. It's very irritating to find a good jquery plugin that can deal with this problem... :(

Can anyone find me a good working one or an alternative to jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following one may suit with your requirement.
http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/

Comment: Awesome exactly what i was looking for too tried nivo-slider but it was kind of a nightmare to work with i don't remember it being that difficult in previous projects.